# NullPointerException in NodeList.getLength() method

Tags: java, xml, dom, nodelist

I am facing one issue with DOM Parser. I have below xml:

```
<problems>
  <problem id = "1">
      <id_value>1</id_value>
  </problem>
  <problem id = "2">
      <id_value>1</id_value>  
  </problem>
</problems>
```

I am using dom parser in java to parse this xml. But when I try to fetch NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("problem"); it sometimes fails.

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl.nextMatchingElementAfter(DeepNodeListImpl.java:199)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl.item(DeepNodeListImpl.java:146)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl.getLength(DeepNodeListImpl.java:117)
```

Here is XMLHandler:

```
try {
    File fXmlFile = new File("C:\\Users\\abc\\workspace\\xml\\problems.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("problem");
    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) { //Exception comes on this line on getLength function
        //do something
    }
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I tried to check doc as well, it has content in it but still when fetching problem element from doc, it fails sometimes. Same code is working majority of the times and fails only few times.

Not sure what is the issue. Thanks in advance for the help.

Note: This block of code is being used in a service controller.

Comment: please edit the question and post a [mcve]

Comment: added java code as well